# The following functions throws an error when I POST data through the call

Tags: python

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def showMessage(error=None):
    message = {
        "status": '404',
        "message": 'Record not found: ' + request.url,
    }
    response = jsonify(message)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

**TypeError: showMessage() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a function.**
Please help with the error.

Comment: You have to check the documentation for whatever framework you are using to see what arguments are going to be passed to your error handler when it gets called. It's getting two arguments, but you only defined it to take a single optional argument.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, since you suggested to check for the arguments passed, I checked for it where ever I made the call, it didn't have brackets. FIXED IT. THANK YOU.